# Angular http put request not sending headers

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http-headers

i am trying to make a http put request from angular to a node js web API  , the request is done correctly  the problem is am not getting the values sent in the header in the node js , i made sure that the problem is in the http put request headers in the angular because i tried the same request with the same header using postman and it went correctly . This is the Angular code  :

```
UpdateRdvById(token){
  let  httpHeader = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
       "token": "test2" ,
       "etat":"test"
    })
  } ;
    return this.http.put(this.base_path+"/user/UpdateRdvByID",httpHeader).pipe()
}
```

Angular log after sending the request :

```
n: 0
nModified: 0
opTime: {ts: "6814399187757564185", t: 10}
electionId: "7fffffff000000000000000a"
ok: 1
$clusterTime: {clusterTime: "6814399187757564185", signature: {…}}
operationTime: "6814399187757564185"
__proto__: Object
```

this the node js code :

```
router.put("/UpdateRdvByID", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var host = req.headers['token'];
   var etat = req.headers['etat'];
    var query = { _id : host };
console.log('id'+req.headers['token']);
console.log('etat'+req.headers['etat']);
    const rdv = await Rendezvous.updateOne(query,{etat:etat});
    res.json(rdv);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err) ;
    res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching rendez vous"+err});
  }
});
```

and here is the problem it's supposed to print values from the headers but it's getting 'undefined' .
node js Log :

```
idundefined
etatundefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two arguments for put method is (URL, body) and the third optional one is the options which contain the headers so you need to change it to:
put(this.base_path+"/user/UpdateRdvByID", null, { httpHeader }).